# jQuery expand menu on specific page using URL no cookies

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this jQuery Menu to automatically expand when the child pages are open. Specifically, I need the child pages of the 'services' section eg. 'graphic design' 'video production' and 'web development' to display the menu in the expanded state. Any Suggestions?

Check out this JS Bin for more info http://jsbin.com/ihoqis/6/edit

```
<div id="primary-nav" data-selectname="Navigate to...">
<div class="menu-navigation-container"><ul id="main-nav" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-11784" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11784"><a title="Interactive" href="#">Interactive</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-12121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-gallery menu-item-12121"><a title="Print" href="#">Print</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15625" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15625"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-20804" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-20802 current_page_item menu-item-20804"><a href="#">Services</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-20816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20816"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-20815" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20815"><a href="#">Video Production</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-20814" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20814"><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Jquery code: I used the suggestions but .show() doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Menu
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/     





    if(jQuery('body').hasClass('mobile')){  // Tablet Hover Fix         
        jQuery("#main-nav li").each(function(){     
        if ($(this).find(".active").length){
       $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('normal');  
   }        
    // check URL for 'services' (may need to be refined to check a specific location
    // in the URL structure)
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("services") > -1) {
    // expand the UL below the LI containing that menu item
    $('a:contains("Services")').parents('li').children('ul').show();
    }
            if(jQuery(this).children('ul').length){ 
                var link = jQuery(this).children('a');                  
                if(link.attr('href') == '#'){
                    link.toggle( function() {jQuery(this).siblings('ul').slideDown("slow"); }, function() {jQuery(this).siblings('ul').slideUp("slow"); });
                }   


                else{
                    var firstClick = true;
                    link.click(function(e){
                    if (firstClick){
                        jQuery(this).siblings('ul').slideDown("slow");
                        firstClick = false;
                        e.preventDefault();    
                    }   
                    });                     
                }
            }
        });     
    }


    else{       
            jQuery("#main-nav li").each(function(){             
                if(jQuery(this).children('ul').length){ 
                    jQuery(this).hoverIntent({
                        interval: 10,  /*Original Value 100*/
                        over: navHoverIn,
                        timeout: 9900, /*Original Value 300*/
                        out: navHoverOut            
                    });
                }
            });
    }


    function navHoverIn () {
            jQuery(this).children('ul').slideDown("slow");
            jQuery(this).addClass("down");
    }

    function navHoverOut () {
            var menu =  jQuery(this);
            jQuery(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow",function() {
                  menu.removeClass("down");
            });          
    }

    var defaultmenu = jQuery('#primary-nav').attr('data-selectname');
    jQuery('#main-nav').mobileMenu({
            defaultText: defaultmenu
    });


    jQuery.event.special.debouncedresize.threshold = 250;
```

Comment: You'll probably either have to hardcode the state into the different pages, parse the URL and figure it out from that, or use cookies / local storage, as there is no magic way to do this.

Comment: You haven't even explained what's wrong with your approach

Comment: I've been trying different approaches all morning I'm looking for some direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
// check URL for 'services' (may need to be refined to check a specific location
// in the URL structure)
if(window.location.href.indexOf("services") > -1) {
   // expand the UL below the LI containing that menu item
   $('a:contains("Services")').parents('li').children('ul').show();
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2QLT/9/)

NOTE: This only works on initial page load or if you use the Update button. Must be something to do with the way the URL is detected. Refresh the page rather than using the Run button.

Comment: This is close to a method I tried earlier, where is the ideal place to insert these lines? Also, I keep getting syntax Errors with the code above.

Comment: Does the quote after contans need to be closed? This was the closest I got  if(window.location.href.indexOf("services") > -1) {

  $('a:contains')("Services").parents('li').children('ul').show();
 }

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors but where should insert the your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I was missing a paren and a quote. It's been fixed. Put the code anywhere you like, but wrap it in document.onload. The jQuery shorthand is $(function() { ... });

Comment: I have it wrapped within the document.onload but .show() doesn't seem to have an effect or it could be that window.location.href.indexOf is not recognizing it's on the 'services' page. I don't see any previous use of .show() but I do see the use of .toggle in the original menu would that work? I tried it with no luck. I could me missing something small. What do you think? Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: I set up a JS Bin to illustrate this more clearly. http://jsbin.com/ihoqis/6/edit The CSS does have a line that sets the ul to display none #main-nav ul {display:none;margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: That's an obscene amount of code for a demo. Take a look at what I added to my answer.

Comment: I can get it to work in the demo fine I can even replicate it in JS Bin but when I apply it to the current script it simply doesn't work. Something within the current menu script is conflicting with the new lines.

Comment: I suggest removing blocks of the script one at a time to see what's conflicting. Maybe we can help once you know that.

Comment: I'ts the minified hover intent script from cherne.net that is causing the conflict.
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html